# Mysql Function within a function what am I missing

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, row

Can get it to display even though in phpMyAdmin it runs fine and gives me the average but when I run it on the webpage it does not display the table

```
<?php
 echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";
 echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";
 echo "<td width='200' align='center'>Avrage Age*</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
include("dbopen.php");
$result = mysql_query("

 SELECT AVG(Age) 
 FROM(
 SELECT N, Dob, Age
 FROM (
 SELECT N, Dob, CURDATE( ) , (
 YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) - YEAR( F ) 
 ) - ( RIGHT( CURDATE( ) , 5 ) < RIGHT( F, 5 ) ) AS Age
 FROM tableages_)alias
 WHERE Age BETWEEN 18 AND 65) As agea ");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {  
 echo "<tr>";  
 echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['agea'] . "</td>";  
  echo "</tr>";  
   }  
 echo "</table>";  
 ?>
```

Comment: what does the markup look like when you run the function?, also did you select the right database?

Comment: Yah I selected the correct DB I have another PHP script runing with the same dbopen.php line and runsa fine, and what markup are you askig? the phpmyadmin runs fine and dislpays this result AVG(Age)  
33.0347  on the php page it does not display the table

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work with a small modification in the sql:

```
SELECT
    AVG(Age) as agea
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            N,
            Dob,
            CURDATE( ) ,
            (YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) - YEAR( F )) - ( RIGHT( CURDATE( ) , 5 ) < RIGHT( F, 5 ) ) AS Age
        FROM tableages_
    ) alias
WHERE Age BETWEEN 18 AND 65
```

and you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get the result as `$row['agea']`. Ohh and there will be only a single row, so don't use a while loop, it is not necessary.

Btw I don't recommend you to use the mysql driver, it's old and has security issues. You should use the [PDO driver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead. In that you should use a fetch column on your statement.